# Python: Passing self to class methods or arguments

Tags: python, oop

I am working on a python project with classes that have quite a few parameters and methods. In order to reduce complexity, I have been writing the methods as such:

```
def foo(self):
    return self.parameter1 * self.parameter2
```

Would it be better practice to explicitly pass the parameters?

```
def foo(self, parameter1, parameter2):
    return parameter1 * parameter2
```

This comes up because I have found it difficult to test the functions in the class without testing the entire class.

Comment: If your method doesn't use `self`, is there a reason to put it on the class?  Note that I'm not advocating that you just put all sorts of data willy-nilly in your class, or that you have your class end up as some sort of state-management nightmare ... Basically, there isn't nearly enough information here for us to make an informed recommendation :-)

Comment: @MYGz Sorry, didn't realize that my question was lacking.. Would it be better to write two example classes rather than just the methods?

Answer (score 5):

Your question makes some assumptions that are not consistent with OO design.

If `parameter1` and `parameter2` *are not* intrinsic properties of the object represented by `self`, then they need to be passed. If however, they *are* intrinsic properties of `self`, then they should have already been associated with `self` and do not need to be passed.

One major point of OO design, and objects in general, is to explicitly associate the data describing the object and the methods to work on the object together.

**Answer:**

Use a `self` reference for anything that is intrinsic to the object, and pass as a parameter those values which are not.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to reduce complexity, I have been writing the methods as such

The assumption of this purpose is wrong, self(instance variable) is supposed to be used if you define an instance method.

> According to [pylint: method_could_be_a_function](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/correctness/method_could_be_a_function.html): If a function could be run without self(instance variable), it should be an individual function, not an instance method.

For example:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_instance_var

    def some_instance_method(self):
        #code here is suggested to be related to self(instance variable), eg:
        return self.some_instance_var
```

---

This one would be proper to put into class as an instance method.

```
class A(object):

    ...

    def foo(self):
        return self.parameter1 * self.parameter2
```

And this one should be a normal function, not an instance method. Because the content of function is not related to self(instance variable).

```
def foo(self, parameter1, parameter2):
    return parameter1 * parameter2
```

Comment: pylint is a tool which is recommended by google, for making code clean and better. You can get more information [here](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)